# PHP Preg match - get wrapped value

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I d like to extract all wrapped text value using preg match

So

```
background: url("images/gone.png");
color: #333;
...

background: url("images/good.png");
font-weight: bold;
```

From above string,
I want to grab

```
images/gone.png
images/good.png
```

What will be the right command line for this?

Comment: You can use sabberworm CSS parser: https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php, you should this:

```
$str = <<<CSS
    background: url("images/gone.png");
    color: #333;

    background: url("images/good.png");
    font-weight: bold;
CSS;

preg_match_all('/url\("(.*?)"\)/', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Then, you will see something like this as an output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(22) "url("images/gone.png")"
    [1]=>
    string(22) "url("images/good.png")"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "images/gone.png"
    [1]=>
    string(15) "images/good.png"
  }
}
```

Therefore, the list with the urls will be in `$matches[1]` :)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/e3u

This regex will do that:

```
/^background: url\("(.*?)"\);$/
```

Better learn some about regex, its worth the time:
http://regexone.com/

Answer (score 2):

```
$pattern = '/(?:\"([^\"]*)\")|(?:\'([^\']*)\')|(?:\(([^\(]*)\))/i';
$string = '
background: url("images/gone.png1");
background: url(\'images/gone.png2\');
background: url(images/gone.png3);
color: "#333;"';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string,$matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

The regular expression will fetch all occurrences of string enclosed in double quotes.

In case you want only fetching background, we can add the same string in regex pattern.

Comment: There are several CSS properties that can be enclosed between quotes (for example the property `content`). As an aside, `url("images/gone.png")` can be written with single quotes or without quotes too.

Comment: If I understood correctly enclosed mean - 1. within single quote. 2. within double quote. 3. within parenthesis. Please correct me if I misunderstood.

Comment: There are always parenthesis around the image path, quotes only are optional. But as I said in comments, it's better to use a parser because there are too many traps in a CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

```
$regex = '~background:\s*url\([\"\']?(.*?)[\"\']?\);~i';
$mystr = 'background: url("images/gone.png");
color: #333;
...

background: url("images/good.png");
font-weight: bold;';
preg_match_all($regex, $mystr, $result);
print_r($result);

***Output:***
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => background: url("images/gone.png"); [1] => background: url("images/good.png"); ) [1] => Array ( [0] => images/gone.png [1] => images/good.png ) )
```